# Jasmine-spec-reporter: How to disable "Expected" description of a failed spec

Tags: jasmine-spec-reporter

Is it possible to configure the "jasmine-spec-reporter" to NOT display the Expected description of a failed spec.

For instance, in the output below, do not print the last row "*Expected true to equal false.*" :

```
 √ [ 1 ] May NOT enter the system when mandatory fields are empty
        × [ 2 ] There is NO "Null Pointer Exception"
          - Expected true to equal false.
```

Comment: Not for now, do you really want to not know why your tests have failed?

Comment: @BastienCaudan, thank you for your response. In my case it is not necessary since I have clear description of SUIT & SPEC as well. In the case my test works properly and a spec failed, the cause should be investigated by developer and not by me (QA), and description like "Expected x but received y" does not make sense for me as well as for developer.

Answer (score 0):

With 3.1.0 version, you could use **spec.displayErrorMessages** and **summary.displayErrorMessages** options:

```
new SpecReporter({
  spec: {
    displayErrorMessages: false
  },
  summary: {
    displayErrorMessages: false
  }
})
```